# FFMPEG: How to convert VFR to CFR without messing up the timing

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I got a video of the iOS simulator recorded with

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo raw.mov
```

This video has a variable framerate

```
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1), 1242x2688, 2268 kb/s, 32.84 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
```

The timing messes up when transcoding the video with any command to a CFR video.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i raw_ios_recording.mov -filter:v fps=60 -fps_mode:v cfr -vsync 1 -copytb 0 out.mp4
```

But any other variation/ permutation to transcode the video to CRF creates the same artifact.

(such as `ffmpeg -i in.mov out.mp4`).

I'm wondering if this is a bug in FFmpeg or am I misunderstanding something?

Here is an example of a video that breaks (I can't upload it to a video-sharing site as it changes the video):

https://storage.googleapis.com/app_recorder_releases/raw_ios_recording.mov

Here is the transcoded version:

https://storage.googleapis.com/app_recorder_releases/ios_simulator_recording_converted_to_60_fps.mp4

Notice how the timing is completely off when opening the first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifacts looks like video encoding (compression) artifacts, and not framerate conversion artifacts.

The framerate conversion also applies video **re-encoding**/[transcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding) (which we can't avoid).
Any re-encoding operation reduces the quality of the video, and adds some artifacts (unless the codec is "lossless" and the output file gets huge).

The default FFmpeg codec for MP4 file is usually H.264, but in your case, the video codec of `out.mp4` is H.263 resulting poor video quality.
Note that the video codec of the input is H.265 (HEVC).

We may select H.265 (HEVC) codec with `-crf 17` argument for (for example) getting better quality:

`ffmpeg -y -i raw_ios_recording.mov -filter:v fps=60 -fps_mode:v cfr -copytb 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 17 -tag:v hvc1 out.mp4`

---

In case your version of FFmpeg doesn't support `libx265`, you may update FFmpeg, or use [hevc_videotoolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924728/optimally-using-hevc-videotoolbox-and-ffmpeg-on-osx) assuming you are using a Mac.

In case the quality is still not good enough we may try adding `-pix_fmt yuv444p` argument and/or reducing the `crf`:

`ffmpeg -y -i raw_ios_recording.mov -filter:v fps=60 -fps_mode:v cfr -copytb 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 10 -tag:v hvc1 -pix_fmt yuv444p out.mp4`

---

**Update:**

Fixing the video timing:

For fixing the timing we may have to ignore the DTS timestamps by adding `-fflags +igndts` argument:

`ffmpeg -y -fflags +igndts -i raw_ios_recording.mov -filter:v fps=60 -fps_mode:v cfr -copytb 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 17 -tag:v hvc1 out.mp4`

---

Using FFprobe command: `ffprobe -show_packets raw_ios_recording.mov` we can see that there are negative DTS timestamps:

`dts_time=-1.283333`
`dts_time=-0.818333`
`dts_time=-0.813333`
`dts_time=-0.805000`
`dts_time=-0.800000`
`dts_time=-0.798333`
`...`

I don't know why there are so many negative DTS, and how FFmpeg handles them.
It seems like ignoring all the DTS timestamps generates video with correct timing.

Comment: I just tried your ffmpeg command, and it indeed improves the quality of the output video. But the timing is still off - in the original video, the app opens at around second 2 whereas the transcoded video opens the app at around second 1.

It originally seemed to me that in that duration the iOS simulator naturally produced low/no frames (as nothing is moving) and therefore the framerate in the VFR video is low in that portion.

Comment: I updated my answer. It looks like `-fflags +igndts` solves the issue. Please check.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!